# When incrementing a double value in a for loop, how can I make sure it stays relatively round?

Tags: c#, for-loop, double

I have this for loop:

```
for (double x = -1 * (display.Width / zoom); x <= (display.Width / zoom); x += 0.1)
{
    //..
}
```

`x` is initialized to -20 and is compared against 20. Ideally, I would like `x` to be incremented as -20, -19.9, -19.8, etc. In practice, this is not what happens; on some iterations, there is indeed only one digit after the decimal point, but in others, it is not as precise, for example -19.8999999. This is responsible for some very irritating (and hard to find) bugs in my program.

How can I make it so that `x` stays 'relatively round'?

Comment: Using decimal, as people have suggested, is good for your particular case, but does not solve the problem in general. doubles get inaccuracies when the denominator of the fraction has a factor other than two. Decimals have the same problem, they just handle factors of two *or five*. If you were trying for steps of size one third instead of one tenth, you'd have the exact same problem with decimal. Generally it is best to solve these sorts of problems entirely in integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `double` or `float` if you need this kind of accuracy - use `decimal` instead.

This is happening because certain fractions cannot be accurately represented in binary - I suggest reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: David Goldberg's article is great!

Comment: @SonerGönül The addition [Differences Among IEEE 754 Implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#3098) by some anonymous writer is even more helpful because it explains why everything is not so beautiful in reality as one might think reading Goldberg's paper.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the way a `double` is stored.  Try a `decimal` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use integer loop counter, initialized to -200 and compared against 200, and calculate your real `x` in each iteration.

UPD: using Decimal is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you right... why you just round it?

```
Math.Round(x,1)
```

Comment: This is a possibility and can be put into the `for` loop like this: `for (double x = start; x <= end; x = Math.Round(x + 0.1)) { ... }`. In any case one must remember, of course, to assign the return value of `Round` back to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers (Double/Float) aren't accurate, instead use -200 and 200 as an int. That will allow to not have to worry about lack of floating point precision.

For more information about this imprecision, I suggest this document.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Oded I was writing that before your answers popped up, so I just decided to keep typing, however at this point this answer is somewhat pointless...

Comment: Apologies for making accusations.

Comment: @Oded Not a trouble at all.

Answer (score 0):

IF you really want it as precise as possible scale it up so that you can work with `int` or `long`... for example:

```
long _Z = (long) ((display.Width * 10) / zoom);

for (long _x = -1 * _Z; _x <= _Z; _x += 1)
{
    double x = ((double)_x) / 10.0;
    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you must use double you could use like this:

```
double x = 0.0;
while (x <= 3.0)
{
   //Do your stuff
   x = Math.Round(x + 0.1, 1);
}
```